# Ftp Connection Best Practice

Tags: c#, file, ftp, connection

I'm using ftp connection for file operations. I want to learn about best practice of ftp connection. First, I'm read file from ExampleX folder then make some operation of the file. Second, read file from ExampleY folder and make some operation of the file. The answer about this: how many ftp connection do I for read two files? In two connection; read file, operation then close connection twice. In one connection read file, operation twice and close connection one time. Would yo help me? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you close the connection between the operations?

Comment: I thought this, but I'm not sure is this best way.

Comment: Btw, the .NET FTP implementation, `FtpWebRequest`, won't even let you easily close the connection between the operations.